# Unexpected rain less than 24 hours after staining

Tags: painting, rain

I painted some exposed wood surfaces (window beams) with an acrylic/oil mix stain/sealant.  The can said to paint when rain is not expected in 24 hours and that drying time is 24 hours.  I did not see any rain in the forecast, although this time of year it's possible for scattered thunderstorms to show up unpredicted.  Sure enough, only 8 hours later a short downpour rolled through.

Now what?  I examined the wood surfaces and they appear wet although I am not sure if that is simply because the rain touched the surface or if the paint has actually gotten wet.  It wasn't terribly humid last night (< 50%) and the surfaces were looking - not dry - but they had already changed noticeably from the wet sheen when paint is first applied to a duller appearance, so I am thinking maybe after 8 hours they are (hopefully?) dried enough to resist a quick downpour, but what if more rain comes?  I don't see any evidence of running at the moment.  After everything is completely dried out, should I apply another coat just to be safe?  Or do I need to try to sand everything down and try again?  It's a rather irregular (older) wood and not completely smooth even after extensive sanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just love how manufacturers expect that weather be so predictable that one could be assured of no rain in the next 24–48 hours.

Here, in the [land of the world's most unpredictable weather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Northwest), we often cross our fingers, resigned to repaint.  Or put up tarps to deal with the possibility of rain, or tarps are at the ready in case threatening clouds appear.

If the temperature and humidity were conducive to quick curing before the rain, it is probably okay.  More rain won't make much difference, especially if the rain stops and the humidity goes down in a few hours.

If there are a few patches of not-well-cured paint, try gentle use of a hair dryer.  In a few days, see if any touch up is needed.